# Copy internal storage from dead phone to new (same model) phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, internal-storage, water-damage

Hi Android Enthusiasts!

I dropped my Galaxy S3 in water, then pressed some buttons and heard some nasty popping/crackling sounds. hehe

Ok, so now I think it's time for a new phone.

What I'm thinking is that I can get the exact same model, then copy all the data over (I'm guessing the internal storage is probably not damaged).

The question is, how can I do this? I'd like to flash the new phone with the image of the old phone, but the old phone doesn't work so I can't use a simple tool like clockwork to make an image backup.

Is it possible to get the data some how?

Answer (score 1):

Internal storage doesn't not use the circuitry in the phone. There's no telling what's been fried, but an audible sound is not good. Next time you drop your phone in water, let it dry before you try using it.

Plug the phone into a PC using it's data cable. If it mounts, extract the data. If it doesn't mount, check the PC's device manager and see if any devices are showing up in the list that aren't being recognized by your OS. If there's nothing there, then you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't turn the phone on, you're screwed. I'm not sure what you think the internal storage is apart from "electronics": it's a chip soldered to the main board of your phone.

Next time, try to make a backup *before* you get your phone wet. It's much easier that way.

Comment: Do you know if the entire OS is stored on the internal storage (cyanogen mod plus all my apps)? I think maybe I can cut off the chip, then find the API for it and reconnect it to some programmable interface like a raspberry pi or arduino, then get the data off it.

Comment: You won't be able to *cut* off the chip. I expect you'd need an oven to desolder it. The internal storage is partitioned like a hard disk. The OS is stored on one partition, and the data on another.

Comment: Sounds a bit hard to do at home! Thanks for the info.